# Drag and drop items out of Surface LibraryBar to remove them?

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-and-drop, wpf-4.0, pixelsense

in my WPF4 & Surface Toolkit 1.5 Beta project I have a Surface LibraryBar with built-in drag and drop features. I also have a user control where I can drag and drop an item of the LibraryBar, to process it there. Another feature I would like to implement is, just dragging an item out of the LibraryBar somewhere else, not having a specific drop target, to remove it from the LibraryBar.

How can I handle that without having a specific WPF control with an explicit `AllowDrop="True"` attribute and a `SurfaceDragDrop.Drop` event handler?